# How to create a copy of an entire NLog logger?

Tags: logging, log4net, nlog

I am in process of replacing log4net with NLog in one project. I want to support option for copying logger with all of its appenders.
This is the current log4net implementation for creating loggers.

```
public static ILog CreateAddonLog(string addon)
{
    XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(GetLogFilePath()));

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(addon))
    {
        return LogManager.GetLogger(DEFAULT_ADDON);
    }
    else
    {
        return GetOrCreateRepostitory(addon, DEFAULT_ADDON);
    }
}
```

Creating copy of base add-on logger:

```
private static ILog GetOrCreateRepostitory(string name, string sourceLogger)
{
    var repoName = $"{sourceLogger}{name}";

    if (LogManager.GetAllRepositories().Any(r => r.Name.Equals(repoName)))
    {
        return LogManager.GetLogger(repoName, repoName);
    }

    var repository = LogManager.CreateRepository(repoName);
    var repo = (Hierarchy)repository;

    CloneAppenders(name, sourceLogger).ForEach(a =>
    {
        repo.Root.AddAppender(a);
        repo.Root.Level = ((Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root.Level;
        BasicConfigurator.Configure(repository, a);
    });

    repo.Configured = true;

    return LogManager.GetLogger(repoName, repoName);
}
```

Cloning all appenders:

```
private static List<IAppender> CloneAppenders(string instanceName, string sourceLogger)
{
    var source = LogManager.GetLogger(sourceLogger);

    var appenders = source.Logger.Repository.GetAppenders()
                        .Where(a => a.Name.EndsWith(sourceLogger))
                        .ToList();

    var result = appenders.Select(a =>
    {
        if (a is EventLogAppender src)
        {
            var clone = new EventLogAppender
            {
                ApplicationName = $"{src.ApplicationName}-{instanceName}",
                LogName = src.LogName,
                Layout = src.Layout,
                MachineName = src.MachineName,
                Name = $"{src.Name}{instanceName}",
                Threshold = src.Threshold
            };

            if (src.FilterHead != null)
            {
                clone.AddFilter(src.FilterHead);
            }

            clone.ActivateOptions();

            return clone;
        }
        else
        {
            return a;
        }
    });

    return result.ToList();
}
```

Is something like this even possible with NLog?

Comment: Can you give an example where this clone-operation is useful ?

Comment: Hi, during runtime I need to copy logging configuration from base addon (outside of my scope) to 10-20 other addons.

Comment: Sounds like the base-addon should have a LoggingConfiguration-Factory (Takes isolated LogFactory as input-parameter), and the factory-method creates/loads the LoggingConfiguration every time it is called. The same factory-method is used for loading the initial-configuration, but also for creating any additional LoggingConfiguration-objects. I guess you should decide whether each addon has their own LogFactory, or if you are letting them all share the same global LogManager.

Comment: But it actually looks like it is a swallow clone (Except from `EventLogAppender`). So maybe you should not make any clone, but just give the plugin-addon its own NLog Logger-object from the global NLog LogManager. Like this `NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(addon).WithProperty("PluginAddon",addon)` and then use `${event-properties:PluginAddon}` in the NLog-EventLog-Target Source-Name.

Answer (score 0):

Think all plugin-addons should just share the same LogManager-configuration (Since you current solution performs shallow clone of log4net appenders):

```
public static ILogger CreateAddonLog(string addon)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(addon))
    {
        return LogManager.GetLogger(DEFAULT_ADDON);
    }
    else
    {
        return LogManager.GetLogger(addon).WithProperty("PluginName", addon);
    }
}
```

And then define you EventLog-target like this:

```xml
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="EventLog"
          name="EventLog"
          source="ApplicationName-${event-properties:PluginName:whenEmpty=Core}" />
</targets>
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Eventlog-target